# Cannot dump object to json file

Tags: python, html, json

I'm trying to dump a python object to json file.

```
with open('test.json', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump([a], f)
```

But i got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users/Lee/Desktop/BeautyProductsScraping-master2/test.py", line 30, in <module>
    json.dump([a], f)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 178, in dump
    for chunk in iterable:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 427, in _iterencode
    yield from _iterencode_list(o, _current_indent_level)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 324, in _iterencode_list
    yield from chunks
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 403, in _iterencode_dict
    yield from chunks
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 436, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 180, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <!DOCTYPE html>
```

How to deal with the html in my object?

Comment: what are the contents of `a`?

Comment: shouldn't this be tagged with python? I don't know python but I would guess you can't serialise the HTML to JSON because maybe it's a string, not an object?

Comment: Thank you! I should have tagged python. Problem is solved once I removed the html from the object's content.